# Disable "Sign in" popup in IIS with Anonymous Authentication disabled

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, web-config, impersonation

I have a intranet asp.net site that uses Windows Authentication. The `Web.config` is:

```
...
<system.web>
  ...
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <identity impersonate="true" />
  <roleManager enabled="false">
  </roleManager>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="MyRole" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
  ...
</system.web>
...
```

Myself and a couple of other users having the `MyRole` role have access to the site, but one other user that does not have the role is seeing a "Sign in" popup asking for credentials.

In IIS `Anonymous Authentication` is `disabled` and only `ASP.NET Impersonation` and `Windows Authentication` are `enabled`.

Could you please advise if there is a way to disable the popup asking for user's credentials?

Comment: you could try to set `<authorization>
    <allow users="user1, user2"/>
    <deny users=”?”/>
</authorization>` [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/323176/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal, the problem with using usernames in `Web.config` is that we need to allow access based on the role, not the username.

Comment: in iis, there is no such kind of setting but you could do some setting in browser like ie. in ie select internet options->select local internet->custom level->Under User Authentication, select Automatic logon with current user name and password.[imae1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D3Zf.png) and [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap4Wv.png)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal, the problem is that we need to disable the pop-up on the server side without making any changes in the browser.

Comment: in my opinion, there is no option to disable pop up at server side.